# how to know if ther is new version in svn?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm using `eclipse` with `subclipse` `svn`.

We are working in two programmers in the same application.

Sometimes, the user 1 changes some code in a specific class.

How can the user 2 know that changes were made?

Is there a way to make eclipse verify the changes in the server from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project in the Project Explorer, then click the Team submenu, then click "Synchronize with Repository" (or click "History" if you want to see the latest commits).

If you want, you can also right click on a file and click "Compare With" then "Latest from Repository" - and it will open a side-by-side comparison.  Or, you can use the SVN Repository Explorer (in the menu bar click "Window" then "Open Perspective", then "SVN Repository Explorer" - if it's not in the list, click "Other..." and then find it.)

Comment: This actually worked for me, at least i can see if there is changes before doing something in the code and end messing it up.

Comment: I added some more info on other ways to look at the file including how to compare.

Answer (score 0):

> How can the user 2 know that changes were made?

Without actually pulling the file(s) down, you can look at the checkin log (history), or do a diff of specific files/folders, otherwise just do an Update. Some wrappers (e.g. a VS IDE plugin, say) will also indicate in the explorer whether or not a file is checked out, locked, out of date, conflicted etc.

> Is there a way to make eclipse verify the changes in the server from time to time?

Yes, use the command line, shell extension, or IDE plugin to do an Update.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I like, that has nothing to do with Eclipse, is to add a post-commit hook in the repository that sends emails when a commit happens.  This is what most open-source projects use.

In Eclipse, you can do Team > Synchronize.  Once the view is open, note that there is a way to "Pin" the Synchronization and also to Schedule it.  Using these features you can setup Eclipse to automatically refresh the information every N minutes.  That way, you do not have to specifically run the option.  Eclipse will always do it for you on the schedule you specify.